# Convert output of pgrep into an integer array

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I want to convert a list of numbers into an array of integers.

@ **n.sh**

```
a=$(pgrep node)
echo $a
```

OUTPUT:

```
5889 6235 6626 6632
```

I have tried to split this by space, using the code

```
#!/bin/bash

OIFS=$IFS;
IFS="|";

Pid=$(pgrep node);
PidArray=($Pid);

for ((i=0; i<${#PidArray[@]}; ++i)); do     echo "pid $i:${PidArray[$i]}"; done

IFS=$OIFS;
```

However,instead of splitting, the string has gone into the `PidArray[0]`

Comment: Please note that Shell doesn't have arrays support, maybe you meant bash?
Anyway, after `a=$(pgrep node)` you could use `for pid in $a; do printf "%s\n" "$pid"; done`.
Substitute `printf` with what you want to use [:

If you need to use arrays, don't change IFS because it is already a space by default!
I hope this will help [:

Answer (score 1):

When I try :

```
pid="1 2 3 4";pida=($pid);for ((i=0;i<${#pida[*]};i++)); do echo $i"="${pida[$i]};done
0=1
1=2
2=3
3=4
```

Should work.

Comment: Thanks @Andre Gelinas
Could you explain what this means --> ${#pida[*]}
It worked but i'd like to know what went wrong with my code

Comment: It's a slightly less correct form of `${#pida[@]}`; as long as you are not quoting the variable anyway, they are equivalent.

Comment: @Wisam Ahmed .. Correct in that context, total number of array elements, both syntax are equivalent. It's only the way I've been taught to do it. In other context it might makes a difference, like for $* compared to $@ .

Answer (score 0):

Setting `IFS="|"` at the top of the script is exactly wrong. You are telling the shell to split input on pipe characters instead of whitespace. For this reason, your array assignment is a single element with spaces in it.

As an aside, the trailing semicolons are also useless.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Avoid creating a variable which is only used once
# Pid=$(pgrep node)
PidArray=($(pgrep node))

for ((i=0; i<${#PidArray[@]}; ++i)); do
    echo "pid $i:${PidArray[$i]}"
done
```